# Cortex-M7: What's the most efficient way to convert a 64-bit unsigned integer to a single-precision floating point number in assembler?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, arm, cortex-m, floating-point-conversion

When I want to convert a 32-bit unsigned integer (e.g. residing in register r0) to a single-precision floating-point number for the VFP (e.g. to be stored in s0), I use:

```
vmov.f32        s0, r0
vcvt.f32.u32    s0, s0
```

However, surprisingly (to me at least) there's no assembly instruction for the conversion of 64-bit unsigned or signed integers to single-precision (or double-precision) floating-point numbers.

My way of getting this done looks like this:

```
bottomInt       .req r0
topInt          .req r1
bottomFloat     .req s0
topFloat        .req s1

@ Convert the 64-bit unsigned int:
vmov.f32         bottomFloat, bottomInt             
vcvt.f32.u32     bottomFloat, bottomFloat
vmov.f32         topFloat, topInt
vcvt.f32.u32     topFloat, topFloat

@ Prepare multiplication with 2^32:
multiplierInt    .req r2                            
multiplierFloat  .req s2
mov              multiplierInt, #0x10000
vmov.f32         multiplierFloat, multiplierInt
vcvt.f32.u32     multiplierFloat, multiplierFloat

@ Multiply the upper word of the unsigned int:
vmul.f32         topFloat, multiplierFloat          
vmul.f32         topFloat, multiplierFloat

@ Add the two floating-point numbers:
vadd.f32         finalFloat, topFloat, bottomFloat
```

Is there a better, more elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: Which floating point units do you have access to?

Comment: I am using -fpv5-d16.

Comment: Clang stubs this out to `__aeabi_ul2f` which is implemented in a [slightly complex manner](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/master/lib/builtins/floatundisf.c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you propose is inexact even when an exact result is representable, so I wouldn't use that.

The runtime library functions `__aeabi_ul2f` and `__aeabi_ul2d` provide the exact behaviour you have requested.

In a general case I would suggest that you should just call these functions.
For example, like: https://godbolt.org/z/j7jT6eWGY

If (and only if) you need to do this repeatedly in piece of code that is such a hot-spot within your program that you cannot afford the overhead of a function call, then I suggest you disassemble the library code for these functions and place it inline.

Comment: I've downvoted your answer because it does not actually explain  how to do the conversion.

Comment: It uses r0 (lower 32 bits) and r1 (upper 32 bits) of the 64-bit int and returns the float in IEEE format in r0. It clobbers r3. While it returns the correct value, I am struggling with hard faults. But that may be related to my lack of knowledge how to deal with the LR register within my interrupt routine where this conversion is happening.

Comment: @Hansel it also clobbers r12 and a few other things (like the flags) just the same any other function.  The stack also must be 8-byte aligned on entry (the same as any externally linked function).  If you want general advice on how to call a function then you will need to edit the question to include a bit of the calling code to see what you have done wrong.

Comment: @fuz, I think I have stated clearly that the correct way to do the conversion in most circumstances is to call the function.  Do you want me to write in out in assembly?  `bl __aeabi_ul2f`.  I deliberately didn't include the library disassembly because I want to encourage people to do this the right way and if the OP is doing this as a learning exercise he will learn more by disassembling it himself.

Comment: Those libgcc functions are GPL or LGPG licensed.  I don't think disassembling works around that, so you might as well look at the libgcc source code.  Google found a copy of the relevant code at https://github.com/OP-TEE/optee_os/blob/203ee23d005b2cec2f21b5de334c5a246be32599/lib/libutils/isoc/arch/arm/softfloat/source/ui64_to_f32.c I think.  Seems to actually be BSD-3-clause licensed.

Comment: @TomV, Thanks for the hint. After making sure that also r12 is pushed onto the stack, it started working for me (not sure why I missed it when I looked through the code). Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @TomV I expect an explanation of the algorithm used to obtain this functionality so it can be done without calling into a library.